# Не удается писать в файл через StreamWriter

Tags: файлы, .net-core, filestream, f#

Создал проект: "Консольное приложение Net Core F#". Код единственного исходника:

```
//backup script
open System.IO
open System
  let main =
    let currDir = @"C:\Users\Antony\source\repos\Test REPOS\backup"
    Environment.CurrentDirectory <- currDir
    let out = new StreamWriter(File.Create("output.txt"))
    let appData, gameData =  "SNAppData", @"C:\Users\Antony\source\repos\Test REPOS\SNAppData" 

    let rec Copy (source: DirectoryInfo) (dest: DirectoryInfo) = 
        source.GetFiles() |> Seq.iter(fun file -> out.WriteLine("Backup {0} complete", file.CopyTo(dest.FullName + "\\" + file.Name).Name) )
        source.GetDirectories() |> Seq.iter(fun dir -> Copy (dir) (Directory.CreateDirectory(dest.FullName + "\\" + dir.Name)))
        out.WriteLine("Backup folder - {0} complete.", source.FullName)
        ()

    if Directory.Exists appData then
        if Directory.Exists "old" then
            Directory.Delete ("old", true)
        Directory.CreateDirectory "old" |> ignore
        Directory.Move(appData, @"old\SNAppData")

    let sourceDir, destDir = Directory.CreateDirectory(gameData), Directory.CreateDirectory(appData)
    Copy sourceDir destDir
    out.Write "FFFF"
    out.Flush
    out.Close
```

Это скрипт для бекапа папки.
Код выполняется быстро и я ожидаю увидеть хотя бы 2 строки в файле output.txt, но он пуст! Как неясно. До его не было, то есть я уверен, что именно мой код создал файл output в целевой папке.
Ну и скриншот папки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обнаружил немного странное поведение: Directory.Delete ("old", true) падает с ошибкой "папка не пуста", хотя вторым параметром я явно указал, что мне нужно рекурсивное удаление. Если компилировать скрипт и запускать с правами админа, то такой ошибки не наблюдается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка довольно простая, но и не самая очевидная.

Дело в том, что в F# функции тоже являются значениями, а следовательно такой код хоть будет считаться корректным:

```
out.Flush
out.Close
```

но имеет другой смысл. Здесь вы на самом деле не вызываете методы, а только лишь ссылаетесь на них.

То есть, чтобы увидеть результаты вам нужно в действительности их вызвать:

```
out.Close()
```

Но, строго говоря, в явном вызове `Close` (как и `Flush`) здесь нет необходимости.

Аналогом `using` из C# является ключевое слово `use` которое и используют вместо `let`:

```
use out = new StreamWriter(File.Create("output.txt"))
```

Результат будет аналогичным - вы увидите корректно записанный файл.

Подробнее читайте в документации:

[use Binding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/resource-management-the-use-keyword#use-binding)

Comment: Получается, что ф-ция FunctionName arg действительно выполнится, только если ни одна из ее перегрузок, учитывая тип arg, не подразумевает дополнительных аргументов? Тогда для 100% гарантии надо всегда использовать FunctionName (arg, arg1)?